# Closed two-sided ideals in $C(X,M_n)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

As is known (see [Kadison-Ringrose](http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-15), 3.4.1) each closed ideal $I$ in the $C^*$-algebra $C(X)$ of continuous functions on a compact space $X$ has the form
$$
I=\{f\in C(X): \ \forall x\in S\quad f(x)=0 \}
$$
for some closed subset $S$ in $X$.

> Is the same true for the two-sided ideals in the $C^*$-algebra $C(X,M_n)$ of continuous maps $f:X\to M_n$ into the algebra $M_n$ of all $n\times n$ complex matrices?

Comment: This turned out to be simple, I am sorry. It seems to me, this could be moved to mathstackexchange.

Comment: An alternative solution is that $C(X)$ and $M_n(C(X))$ are *Morita-Rieffel equivalent* and this implies that they have the same lattice of ideals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your compact space $X$ is Hausdorff.  Then the answer is yes.

Suppose $I$ is a closed two-sided ideal in $C(X, M_n)$.
For each $x \in X$, $I(x) = \{f(x): f \in I\}$ is a two-sided ideal in $M_n$.  But 
$M_n$ is a simple ring: it has no two-sided ideals except itself and $\{0\}$.
Let $S = \{x \in X: \; I(x) = \{0\}\}$.  Then $I \subseteq I(S) = \{f \in C(X, M_n):\; f|_S = 0\}$.

Now suppose $f \in I(S)$.  I need to show $f \in I$. For each $x \notin S$, $I(x) = M_n$ so there is some $g_x \in I$ with $g_x(x) = f(x)$.  Given $\epsilon > 0$,  we can find a finite partition of unity $\rho_1, \ldots, \rho_N$ of $X$ and $g_1, \ldots, g_N \in I$ such that $\|f(x) - \sum_j \rho_j(x) g_j(x)\| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in X$.  Since $I$ is closed, $f \in I$.